# Asc files and Matlab: How to read the coordinates

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I'm very new to matlab and am more of an ArcGIS user but I'd like to know how I can read asc files into Matlab and read coordinates.

The asc file is as follows (sorry it is huge!)

```
ncols   32          
nrows   32          
xllcenter   -58.75          
yllcenter   -38.75          
cellsize    2.5         
NODATA_value    -999            
0.00    0.62    0.60    0.38    1.22
0.52    1.09    0.76    0.00    0.94
0.37    0.52    0.71    0.71    1.38
0.13    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.46
0.00    0.00    0.97    0.00    0.41
0.00    0.00    0.41    0.83    0.00
0.00    0.19    0.32    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.86    0.00    0.52    1.34
0.00    1.29    0.00    0.00    1.40
0.83    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    1.09    0.20    0.00
0.43    0.00    0.96    0.78    0.26
0.00    0.70    0.00    0.92    0.29
0.00    1.19    0.00    1.24    0.73
0.00    1.41    0.00    0.97    1.01
0.66    0.00    0.01    0.67    0.67
0.32    0.69    1.41    0.00    0.08
0.92    0.00    0.00    0.40    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.27    1.24
0.22    0.00    0.00    0.76    0.86
0.00    0.05    0.67    0.29    0.00
0.00    0.04    0.00    0.00    1.18
0.46    0.20    0.00    0.81    0.00
0.00    0.00    1.35    0.40    1.03
0.94    0.90    0.80    0.26    0.73
0.69    0.36    0.70    0.00    0.00
0.42    1.23    0.00    1.24    0.52
0.00    0.54    1.39    1.44    0.00
1.18    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.78
1.33    0.58    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.92    0.00    0.00    0.00
1.03    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.66    0.92    0.73    0.00    0.99
0.00    0.00    1.39    0.49    0.97
0.00    1.29    0.00    1.41    1.06
0.00    1.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.32    0.69    1.26    0.00
0.00    0.71    0.00    1.08    1.16
0.00    0.00    0.48    0.00    1.17
0.24    0.00    0.00    0.41    0.00
1.24    1.30    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.23    0.00    0.15    0.00
0.00    0.19    0.00    0.00    1.17
1.41    0.00    0.15    0.48    0.20
1.29    0.00    0.22    0.55    0.00
0.00    0.81    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.18    1.18    0.00    0.75
1.05    1.18    1.35    0.00    0.82
0.00    0.00    0.25    0.52    0.00
0.00    1.27    1.46    0.00    1.24
0.00    1.03    1.21    0.81    0.00
0.57    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1.06    0.00    1.29    0.70    0.00
0.00    1.01    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.21    0.95    0.00    0.00    0.00
1.23    1.08    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.11    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.76    0.00    0.68
0.10    0.64    0.00    0.72    0.00
1.34    0.53    0.00    0.18    0.00
0.00    0.25    0.22    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.67    0.37    0.00    0.08
0.02    0.00    0.00    0.94    0.52
0.83    0.64    0.00    0.93    1.40
1.03    0.50    0.00    1.20    0.00
0.68    0.00    0.00    1.15    1.20
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.93    0.00
1.25    0.94    1.37    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.77    0.00    1.15    0.66
0.00    1.45    0.00    1.48    0.00
0.36    0.00    0.34    0.00    0.00
1.22    0.74    0.00    0.00    1.17
0.00    0.59    0.00    0.00    1.18
1.32    1.31    1.21    0.45    1.06
0.00    0.18    0.21    0.79    0.47
0.00    0.47    0.00    0.53    0.76
0.00    0.92    0.00    0.00    1.23
1.45    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1.02    0.00    0.00    0.46    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.38    1.25
0.00    1.25    0.00    0.42    0.17
0.00    0.97    0.20    0.00    0.00
0.31    0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.70    0.66    0.00    1.15
0.00    0.00    0.91    1.10    0.00
0.12    0.73    0.00    0.19    0.00
1.01    0.00    0.44    0.00    0.21
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.91
0.01    0.00    1.28    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.16    0.50    0.00    0.00
1.50    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.07    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.88
0.00    0.43    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.23    0.00    1.41    0.33
0.00    0.74    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.74    0.76    0.15    1.07    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.34    1.20
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.43
0.22    0.00    1.02    0.99    0.80
0.91    0.75    0.02    0.00    0.18
0.25    0.00    0.52    0.60    0.00
1.11    0.43    0.00    0.00    0.83
1.02    0.76    0.20    0.00    1.24
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.21    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.25
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.87
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.47    1.22
0.86    0.00    0.96    0.60    0.70
0.38    0.09    0.85    1.18    0.49
0.03    0.00    0.00    1.23    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.06    0.00
1.01    1.39    1.01    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.31
0.00    0.75    0.00    1.22    0.81
1.07    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.12
1.05    0.70    0.13    0.64    1.30
0.00    0.00    0.53    0.47    0.03
0.00    0.00    0.10    1.38    1.32
0.00    1.25    0.00    0.91    0.67
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
1.00    1.14    0.00    0.00    0.52
0.00    0.02    0.15    0.01    0.90
0.00    0.00    0.70    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.12    0.72    0.00    0.00    0.04
0.01    0.00    0.00    1.11    1.43
0.91    0.34    0.97    0.00    0.07
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.93
0.00    0.93    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.93    0.00    0.88    0.29    0.00
0.00    1.50    0.00    0.05    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.76    1.26
0.00    0.43    0.55    0.40    0.28
0.00    0.07    0.51    0.51    0.00
0.76    0.00    0.00    0.41    0.10
1.16    0.07    0.00    0.00    0.65
0.00    0.21    0.00    0.00    1.41
0.00    1.31    0.19    1.44    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.94    0.00
1.12    0.68    0.00    0.00    0.81
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.96    0.00
0.38    0.00    0.00    0.46    0.00
1.15    0.36    0.70    1.04    0.89
1.47    1.20    0.00    0.35    0.00
0.49    0.00    0.00    1.48    0.00
0.00    0.45    1.42    0.00    1.12
0.00    0.00    1.20    1.27    0.00
0.00    0.68    0.30    0.00    0.00
1.20    0.00    0.89    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.10    0.48    1.48    0.00
1.23    0.00    1.05    0.56    0.86
0.00    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.03
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.03    0.90    0.00
0.00    0.00    1.10    0.11    0.68
0.07    0.00    0.78    1.28    1.06
0.39    0.46    0.26    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.85    0.00    0.81    0.00
0.04    0.86    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.45    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.00
0.50    0.60    0.00    1.33    0.00
1.15    0.00    1.44    0.82    0.00
0.00    0.01    0.65    0.30    0.00
0.03    0.76    1.12    0.00    0.00
0.59    0.00    0.14    1.16    0.75
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.24    0.41    0.54    1.36
0.00    0.06    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.76    0.18    1.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.08    0.00
0.00    0.34    0.00    0.82    0.00
0.54    0.00    0.55    0.00    0.97
1.29    0.22    0.00    0.07    0.00
1.31    1.43    0.00    0.35    1.37
0.81    0.00    0.25    0.00    0.90
0.57    0.58    0.00    0.47    0.00
0.51    0.00    0.00    0.50    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.21    0.23
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.11    0.00
1.08    1.04    0.72    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.15    0.00    0.80
0.00    0.60    0.00    0.00    1.02
0.00    1.27    0.38    0.69    0.00
1.23    0.00    0.68    0.00    0.31
0.00    0.95    0.00    0.09    0.00
0.00    0.28    0.00    0.00    0.45
0.67    0.92    0.53    1.28    0.13
0.00    0.00    1.02    0.51    0.00
0.00    0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    0.31    0.00    0.98
0.00    0.00    0.00    1.15    0.89
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.42    0.00
1.31    1.27    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    1.23    1.13    0.00
1.05    0.00    0.38    0.00    0.00
0.02    0.00    0.14    0.33    0.12
0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
0.00    0.00    1.35    0.18    0.03
0.00    0.00    0.44    0.00    0.00
0.00    1.31    0.19    0.78    0.00
1.17    0.03    1.00    1.02    0.72
```

nrows and ncols are the number of rows/columns

xllcenter and yllcenter are the coordinates of the centre of the square in the bottom left hand corner of the grid

the cell size is the length of one side of a grid square.

I can read the matrix in and choose to print out values according to their position in the matrix but how would I assign coordinates to such a matrix?

Can I then ask matlab to output the appropriate matrix values when I put in coordinates?

Thanks everyone who can offer me advice!

Comment: Why and when do you need to coordinates? I find it easier to simply use the matrix position, as I don't need to convert between decimals in coordinates and the grid position. I have a rough converter between coordinate and position as follows, maybe it is of help for you? 
`laDegrees = 15;` %!! Fill in degrees. Positive N, negative S.
`loDegrees =  105;` %!! Fill in. Positive E, negative W. 
`[diffLa, lati]  = min(abs(latitude-laDegrees)); `
`[diffLo, longi] = min(abs(longitude-loDegrees));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a beginner with Matlab, I suggest you investigate the menu option `File | Import Data` and then study the documentation of the `uiimport` function.